# Young adult book where a teenager finds magic in a library

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I'm trying to remember the title of a book I read a few years ago.  From what I remember, it was probably from the Young Adult section of the library.

The basic premise was a teenager being forced by their parents into taking a summer internship at a local library, only to discover it was filled with all kinds of magical books and objects (somewhat like the Library in The Librarian[s] series, or Warehouse 13).

Unfortunately, I can't remember much more than this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Libraries and bookstores Are where you DO find magic.

Comment: @FlaStorm32 Well, yes, but not generally in the literal sense...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see any indications of having been forced into the internship by anything other than boredom, but Polly Shulman's *[The Grimm Legacy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6760780-the-grimm-legacy)* hits your points:

[image: Front cover of The Grimm Legacy]

> Elizabeth has a new job at an unusual library - a lending library of objects, not books. In a secret room in the basement lies the Grimm Collection. That's where the librarians lock away powerful items straight out of the Brothers Grimm fairy tales; seven-league boots, a table that produces a feast at the blink of an eye, Snow White's stepmother's sinister mirror that talks in riddles.
>
> When the magical objects start to disappear, Elizabeth embarks on a dangerous quest to catch the thief before she can be accused of the crime or captured by the thief.

[This review](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6760780-the-grimm-legacy) mentions a bit more about her motivation:

> Elizabeth at the moment is friendless. Her best friend has moved to California and she is still trying to get accustomed to her new home situation, new stepmother and two step-sisters who thankfully are at a college now. Things start to shift when Elizabeth decides to do her paper in history over the Grimm fairy tales. Elizabeth's history teacher gives her a recommendation to work at a library. But she will find out this is not like any library she has ever been to, in this library you can check out magical objects which of course opens up a whole can of trouble.

Comment: Slightly less likely: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25721477-artifacts

Comment: I think this is probably it.

Comment: @Moko19: If you track it down, and it turns out to not be the right answer, you can always click on the checkmark again to remove acceptance, and then edit into your question non-matching points so that it pops back up to the top of the list. :) No worries on my part.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds a lot like *So You Want to Be a Wizard* by Diane Duane (this was part of a series, ["The Young Wizards"](https://www.dianeduane.com/the-young-wizards-series/) totaling five books).

The main deal is that all spells have a cost, sometimes the cost doesn't seem to make sense (one I recall required a lithium-cadmium battery -- in a book that came out years before lithium batteries were everywhere, I might add) -- and sometimes, they amount to a "blank check" where you don't know up front what it will cost you.

One salient point was that the younger a wizard is when they come into their power, the more powerful they will be -- a teen will be good, an adult barely so-so, but the little sister who found the "book" on a portable Apple III as a pre-teen will be one of the greatest ever (very minor spoiler for the third book).

Comment: Although I don't recall any library internship. I seem to recall they find it while hiding from bullies.

Comment: The two early teens in the first book each found their own book separately, but the main protagonist might well have been hiding.  Doesn't necessarily hit all the keys, but conflated memory is a thing.

Comment: Dairine is actually eleven when she gets her computer.

Comment: I also thought it was interesting how that greater power was tied to that younger age, which meant that Nita and Kit were already starting to feel that decline in the later of the 11 books in the series, so they had to use their power more conservatively.

Comment: I also thought about this book when reading the title of the question, but there is only one book of magic in the library; the library definitely isn't *"filled with all kinds of magical books and objects"*